# Unsure why supabase is not returning values from foreign table

Tags: javascript, supabase, supabase-database

I have a query that also selects from a foreign table. The current table already has a foreign key relationship. Here is my query

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('comments')
        .select('content,created_at,user(pfp,username)')
        .eq('chapter', chapterid)
        .limit(7)
        .select()
```

This is what is returned:
`{id: 5, created_at: "2022-03-03T18:16:20.592125+00:00", user: "7a2750e7-0d25-4a40-9236-ce7a42d61bd2", chapter: "1b4e4595-089e-457c-ac89-9ed4eace0ca9", content: "Woahh"}`

My comments table
[image: Comments Table]

The table the user column references (profile table)

[image: Profile table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/5807)

> You have an extra .select() at end which fetches all columns...